# Is Arabiv ی is romanized/transliterated as u with a line above it?

Tags: arabic, transliteration, romanization

As you can see in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banu_Hashim), Banu Hashem is not بنوهاشم, but بنی هاشم in Arabic.

But *u* is used mostly for و and not for ی.

I'm puzzled here and I can't find a good answer for this.

Could you please help?

Comment: It's a kind of a computer bug with you, for me it's بنو هاشم‎ with و, in all the Wikipedia articles in different languages. Maybe it's about your computer font settings.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of how I see the page you gave a link to: https://i.imgur.com/O2SdcWn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page you link doesn't seem to show the form you see to me. Regardless, I suspect this is an issue of case

بنو هاشم with a wāw is the nominative form of Banū Hāshim, and is used when the noun is the subject of the sentence

بنی هاشم with a yāʼ is the accusative and genitive form, Banī Hāshim, and is used when the noun is the object of a verb, preposition, or is attached to by a noun in the construct state

The macron (the line over the vowel) indicates that it is long

Comment: But I have never heard of بنوهاشم in any text, and I'm an active Islamic researcher. Then how could it be?

Comment: ʾIʿrāb didn't survive into any modern vernacular, and is frequently omitted in Modern Standard Arabic, so it's not surprising that the nominative -ū form has become generalised

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - Is [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/en/index.php?page=aboutus) good for you? Here's [their page](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/66197/%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%88-%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%85-%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%88-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A8-%D9%88%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A-%D8%A3%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA) in Arabic stuffed with mentioning بنوهاشم with و.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Your comments are very confusing. In the question, you say that Banu has <ī> instead of <ū> (I can’t type Arabic on my phone, so I’m using <> instead) on Wikipedia, even though the page seems to have <ū> on other people’s devices. Then in this comment you say you’ve never seen the <ū> form, which seems to be the opposite. Which form is it that you have seen and know? And which form is it you haven’t seen before?